# How can I get weak-tasting tomatoes?

Tags: flavor, tomatoes

I love the weak tomatoes that you get at fast food restaurants like Subway. Whenever I buy tomatoes from the grocery store or the farmer's market, they're too strong and I end up throwing them out.

Do restaurants like Subway use weak breeds of tomatoes, or do they have some kind of process for making their tomatoes weak?

Comment: Tomatoes that have been bred to be able to travel without damage are low in sugar and essential oils, pale, and very firm.  Fast food places use these kinds of tomatoes.  However, it needs to be said that you're essentially throwing away good food because it tastes like what it is, which is absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by weak-tasting. If you mean less flavorful, then you want tomatoes that have been harvested before they are ripe. You should avoid hot house, vine ripened & farmers market tomatoes. You should look for the least expensive slicing or salad tomatoes you can find.

Comment: FYI The nutritional profile of "weak tasting" tomatoes is much the same as full flavour. The ripe flavour is actually the breakdown of the sugars etc in an over ripe tomato

Comment: I was about to say buy cheap, non-orgainc, industrially produced tomatoes but thinking about it I just realized that cheap tomatoes where I live have more flavor (especially acidity) compared to expensive imports. But avoid those marketed as "organic" anyway if you want flavorless tomatoes.

Comment: @WadCheber While I agree in this case (mainly because it's *so hard* to find good tomatoes where I'm from nowadays), it should be noted that it's pretty much analogous to i.e. avoiding cheese that is too smelly or spices that are too spicy. Mildness is a quality of its own, and it's not entirely fair to bash someone for liking a product that seems inferiour to you.

Comment: @Luaan - This is a little different from your cheese example.  Cheese can taste like almost anything.  There are more differences than similarities between, say, a mild cheddar and a strong Limburger, so there is no one thing that you can call "cheese flavor".  Tomatoes grow and you pick them.  That's it.  There are more similarities than differences between tomatoes.  So there is definitely a single "tomato flavor", regardless of slight variations.  This question is asking for tomatoes that don't taste like tomatoes.

Comment: @Wad Cheber no, he is asking how to buy tomatoes that he won't discard :)

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/notes/natural-new-age-mum/subway-ingredients-may-2013-not-so-healthy/607273319296483/   ... couldn't believe my eyes - the tomatoes aren't f...ed with in any official way :)

Answer (score 8):

Buy "hot house" tomatoes, particularly off-season.  You'll be good to go.

Comment: And should you happen to find some that were grown in The Netherlands, immediately buy all of them. We have the best flavorless tomatoes in the world. Their shape is a mathematically proven perfect sphere, their color is a perfect, textbook, tomato-red, and, what I consider to be their only drawback, is exactly what the OP is looking for: Little, to no taste.

Answer (score 6):

Besides buying cheaper, firmer and paler tomatoes as explained above, try also keeping them in the fridge before eating them. Refrigeration breaks down many of the tomato flavors.

Answer (score 2):

I was the same way as the OP and found the lighter coloured Roma tomatoes to suit my tastes best. Very mild tomato flavour even in the brighter red ones. I don't much like tomatoes but I love Roma tomatoes!

Comment: Welcome! Just a hint: we don’t have “threads” in the sense most discussion forums do. This is a Q/A site with the aim of building a persistent collection of information for the asker’s immediate benefit, but probably even more so for future users. So it’s perfectly ok to answer questions that were asked quite a while ago (note that I didn’t say “old question”). What’s also recommend that new users take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works. Again: welcome!